# Requesting a help for validating metrics to compare web application security testing tools

Tags: security, testing, owasp, websecurity

Hey everyone!

My name is AJit Vemula, and I'm currently studying master's in software engineering, in Sweden. I'm working on my thesis, which involves comparing web application security testing tools. One part of my thesis involves identifying relevant metrics for comparison. I've already done a literature review to identify these metrics.

Now, I'm looking to assign points to these metrics based on specific value ranges. For instance, if the metric is "scan time" and the point range is from 1 to 5, I need to figure out which time ranges (e.g., 1 hour) correspond to which points (e.g., 5 points for 1 hour).

To validate the metrics I've identified and determine the point ranges, I'm planning to conduct interviews with experienced professionals in testing like you. If anyone here has experience using web application security scanners and is willing to participate in an interview to help me out, please let me know! Your insights would be incredibly valuable to my research. Thanks!

One critical aspect of my thesis involves meticulously pinpointing the most relevant metrics for comparison. This undertaking commenced with an exhaustive literature review aimed at identifying these pivotal metrics.

Presently, my focus is on intricately assigning points to these identified metrics based on finely delineated value ranges. To elucidate, consider the metric of "scan time"; it necessitates determining which specific time intervals (e.g., 1 hour) correspond to designated point values (e.g., 5 points for 1 hour).

To ensure the validity of the metrics delineated and to establish the precise point ranges, I am devising a plan to engage in comprehensive interviews with professionals within the field of testing, particularly those with substantial experience in utilizing web application security scanners.

If any individuals possessing such expertise are willing to participating in these interviews to provide invaluable insights, I would be immensely grateful for your involvement. Your perspectives hold considerable significance for the advancement of my research. Thank you in advance for considering this request!